# What's the best way/library to parse and work with XML in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, nsxmlparser

My teacher recommended TBXML so I used it, but I've noticed there are others such as the built-in NSXMLParser.
Whatcha say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBXML's site has a link to a nice article about [XML parsers for iPhone](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project). If you've never parsed XMLs before, TBXML's DOM approach will be more intuitive to you.

I've never used TBXML before, but looking at those performance charts it seems that it's quite an efficient parser. I'm actually surprised that it's memory usage isn't higher than that of the SAX parsers.